# PineScript order entry at a horizontal line with a stop loss and take profit

Tags: typescript, orders, price, loss, entry-point

I am new on Pinescript, I want to create a script to trigger a long buy entry at *one tick below* the horizontal line while activating the stop loss/take profit (I'll manually put a horizontal line there) is it possible to do something like this with a pine script?

2

I am just using this exercise to better understand PineScript and once I have a script that can execute the above I plan to then build on that, so this will be a huge help!

Thanks all